# Reading an .arff file and trying to ignore the header

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy, classification, arff

I am a new with python and I need some help with my code. I am reading an . arff file with my jupyter notebook using pyhton2.7.I would like to know which argument I need to put in arff.lodarff  ,or another way to do it, so I can ignore the header of my data.

```
rain,meta = arff.loadarff(open('train.arff', 'r'))
```

After I read the file I am doing some mathematical operations and I got this error.

I hope someone can help me to figure out.

```
train,meta = arff.loadarff(open('train.arff', 'r'))
train = pd.DataFrame(train)
print(train)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-192-3b2868d1fd43> in <module>()
----> 1 ne = getNeighbors(X_train, y_train, X_test, k = 3)
      2 print(ne)

<ipython-input-191-75b4da86d04e> in getNeighbors(X_train, y_train, X_test, k)
      6             for (trainpoint,y_train_label) in zip(X_train,y_train):
      7                 # calculate the distance and append it to a distances_label with the associated label.
----> 8                 distances_label.append((distance(testpoint, trainpoint), y_train_label))
      9             k_neighbors_with_labels += [sorted(distances_label)[0:k]] # sort the distances and taken the first k neighbors
     10         return k_neighbors_with_labels

<ipython-input-186-22e861402349> in distance(testpoint, trainpoint)
      2 def distance(testpoint, trainpoint):
      3     # distance between testpoint and trainpoint.
----> 4     dist = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.power(float(testpoint)-float(trainpoint), 2)))
      5     return dis
      6 

ValueError: could not convert string to float: sepal_length
```

Answer (score 0):

You assume that `testpoint` is an array in your distance function.

But what if it isn't?

You are using pandas dataframes, these are not just arrays, and that is why you get column names.